# RDLC PDF Export throwing error on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, rdlc

In my application users can actually export in pdf format, but after i have uploaded my application to the server, while trying to export, it's throwing **object reference not set to the instance of an object**

the application is working just fine in my local host, i will appreciate any assistance from anyone who may have had similar challenge.

Comment: Could u please provide the code that throws an exception?

Comment: there is no error on my code, i even check the log file no error while hosting on the sever, beside i dont write code for the pdf export, the pdf export comes with the rdlc.

Comment: But if you got this exception you should have a stack trace

Comment: yes, there is stack trace, but i couldn't figure the line causing the error out.